# Make Count reset

Tags: c#, count, reset

The issue I'm having is when I click stop the label resets to zero but when I click start again the counter starts where it last left off. I want to make the counter start at zero each time I click the start button. Here is what I have:

```
    //Perform mouse down followed by mouse up while counting the number of clicks performed.
    int Count = 0;
    private void PerformClick_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Count++;
        CountTxt.Text = Count.ToString();
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0);    
    }

    //Convert our text to int to control our timer speed.
    private void Speed_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int SetSpeed = Int32.Parse(Speed.Text);
        PerformClick.Interval = SetSpeed; 
    }

    //Reset counter to zero after the program is stopped
    private void Reset_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PerformClick.Enabled == false)
        {
            CountTxt.Text = "0";
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Set `Count = 0;` inside the `Reset_Tick` method?

Comment: I assume the variable count is declared globally, I think @DaveZych is righ, set count to 0. Assigning "0" to your label is pointless since in your PerformClick_Tick you assigned count to CountTxt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to reset your Count variable to zero.

Try something like this:

```
private void Reset_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (PerformClick.Enabled == false)
    {
        CountTxt.Text = "0";
        Count = 0;
    } 
}
```

Comment: I'm going to, Cant till after 8 minutes. But I will soon as the 8 minutes are up.

Comment: Oh.. ok, forgot about those time limits.